How to handle random temporary effects with Monte Carlo Tree Search
I wrote a simple two player snake game and trying to implement agents for enemies.
I implemented MCTS what works somehow, but I think the "food" that is randomly dropped and disappears after some rounds confuses the algorithm.
The snake acts pretty ok so far but it completely ignores the food (picks it up sometimes by accident) and stays tiny over the hole game.
Is there a way to lead the search more into picking up food some times?
I thought to backpropagate not just who won but also work the snake's length into the result but I'm not sure how to do it and if this is this really the way to go?

"not just who won": it probably depends on the flavour of the game, but to my knowledge you always "lose" the game, and it is more a game where you can try to maximise your score (snake length) before that happens. What does winning mean here?

It's a two player version. Basically a mashup of snake and tron. The survivor wins.

But then I am surprised that you don't get better results. Are you sure you have implemented MCTS correctly? How have you asserted this?
